# How to get scons to treat a directory itself as a target?

Tags: doxygen, scons

I'm trying to set up a build involving an external tool which produces a directory as output (`doxyindexer` for the curious). So far, I've essentially got these commands:

```
target = "doxysearch.db/iamchert"
doxygen.Doxyindexer(target,["project1.xml","project2.xml","project3.xml"])
Default([target])
Default(Install(ARGUMENTS["cgibin"],"doxysearch.db"))
```

The problem that I'm having is that I think I'd like `target` to be the directory itself, not some random file inside the directory. There's nothing I can glob because the target doesn't exist until I build it and I don't want to presume anything that Dimitri might change! When I use the directory as the target, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Tried to lookup Dir 'doxysearch.db' as a File.:
```

which is why I picked `iamchert` to be the target. Those lines all seem to work as expected, even if my approach is a hack. However, I can't get that last line to work. I need to copy the directory `doxysearch.db` into the `cgi-bin` directory, which is specified on the command line by the user. Maybe someone can explain how to do this step properly? I'm a newb when it comes to scons!

I'm having trouble googling the answer because all the search words involved are too common to find me specific help!

Answer (score 6):

SCons does in fact treat all the files in a dir as dependencies of that dir.  There are some dark corners that need work, but it should work in a simple case like this.

What you need is the undocumented `target_factory` builder flag.  When you define `Doxyindexer` do it like this:

```
doxyindexer = Builder(..., target_factory=env.fs.Dir)
```

and have your builder return the dir itself.  That should avoid the TypeError you were getting.

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure how well SCons will work with the target being a directory. The issue is: How should SCons determine if the directory has changed or not to know if it should be built? The obvious answer would be that a directory is considered to be changed if it has more or less files therein, but I dont think SCons currently does this check and you might have to make your own builder to get it.

I did the following example to test this, and it never builds:

```
env = Environment()
env.Command(target = 'targetDir',
            source = 'srcTextFile',
            action = Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

When I execute SCons, I always get the same result:

```
scons: '.' is up to date
```

Regarding your SCons code, I think it would work better as follows:

```
targetDir = "doxysearch.db/iamchert"
srcFiles = ["project1.xml","project2.xml","project3.xml"]

doxygenTarget = doxygen.Doxyindexer(targetDir, srcFiles)

    # This may need to be called via the Command() builder like this:
    # cmd = "doxygen.Doxyindexer("$TARGET", "$SOURCE")
    # doxygenTarget = env.Command(target=targetDir, source=srcFiles, action=cmd)

# This call to Default isnt really necessary
Default(doxygenTarget)
Install(ARGUMENTS["cgibin"], doxygenTarget)
```

Comment: I guess the issue is how to calculate the "age" the of the directory as a target. One hack could look something like the directory is tar'ed and that is used as the target. I would assume that if that could work, then Scons could implement some way to do it behind the scenes. But it sounds like you're saying that Scons doesn't have the capability.

Comment: @amos, Its definitely possible to do this sort of check in SCons, as its quite extensible, but currently this behavior is not implemented. In addition to what I mentioned about a dir being considered as changed if it has more or less files, some may argue that a directory is changed if files therein have changed. This could become complicated and inefficient rather quickly, as it could be extended to sub-directories.